# How do I inner join 3 tables with the keyword IN OR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How would I use this `IN` `OR` select statement correctly? (Everything actually works except `where bdt.active='yes'`)

```
SELECT bdt.*, specials.*, stars.* 
FROM bdt INNER JOIN specials ON  bdt.id = specials.id 
         INNER JOIN stars ON specials.id=stars.id 
   WHERE bdt.active='yes' 
   AND  bdt.business_type IN ('entertainment') 
    OR  bdt.business_subtype IN  ('entertainment')  
    OR  bdt.subtype2 IN ('entertainment') 
    OR  specials.type IN ('entertainment')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use brackets `()` in second `AND` conditions like this:

```
SELECT bdt.*, specials.*, stars.* 
FROM bdt INNER JOIN specials ON  bdt.id = specials.id 
         INNER JOIN stars ON specials.id=stars.id 
   WHERE bdt.active='yes' 
   AND (bdt.business_type IN ('entertainment') 
    OR  bdt.business_subtype IN  ('entertainment')  
    OR  bdt.subtype2 IN ('entertainment') 
    OR  specials.type IN ('entertainment'))
```

Comment: actually neither one works. I should have disclosed I have a sub query attached to this query that stopped working when i applied the fix. your help is greatly appreciated THANK YOU.

select bdt.*, specials.*FROM bdt INNER JOIN specials ON  bdt.id = specials.id WHERE bdt.active='yes' and specials.date >= CURDATE() and specials.type IN ('entertainment') and bdt.id = ".$row_entertainment['id']." GROUP BY specials.title ORDER BY specials.date, specials.price ASC LIMIT 7";

Answer (score 0):

2 notes about style.

1. Use `IN` when you have multiple choices, use `=` for a single direct match.
2. `SELECT bdt.*, specials.*, stars.*` is really bad form.  From your joins, it's evident each table has an `id` field.  You'll want to list only the columns you need and alias same-named columns differently.

I'll also show below how you can rewrite the `OR` clause using `IN`, correctly.

```
SELECT bdt.*, specials.*, stars.* 
FROM bdt INNER JOIN specials ON  bdt.id = specials.id 
         INNER JOIN stars ON specials.id=stars.id 
   WHERE bdt.active='yes' 
   AND  'entertainment' IN (bdt.business_type, bdt.business_subtype,
                            bdt.subtype2, specials.type)
```

Comment: that works also but how would you write it if there were a list of variables
SELECT bdt.*, specials.*, stars.* 
FROM bdt INNER JOIN specials ON  bdt.id = specials.id 
         INNER JOIN stars ON specials.id=stars.id 
   WHERE bdt.active='yes' 
   AND (bdt.business_type IN ('entertainment','bars','nightclubs') 
    OR  bdt.business_subtype IN ('entertainment','bars','nightclubs') 
    OR  bdt.subtype2 IN ('entertainment','bars','nightclubs') 
    OR  specials.type IN ('entertainment','bars','nightclubs'))